# How to extract either only digits or full string incl digits

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract system names from a list that are made up of numbers and characters like this
FH9989BP
DETV98-05
998-534

I need it to return only the digits for FH9989BP --> 9989 but the whole name for all the other cases.

When I am trying

```
import re
names = "FH9989BP, DETV98-05, 998-534"
system = re.findall(r'(\d{4})',names)
```

it returns (as expected) *9989*

to get the others I've been trying to add the | switch like this

```
import re
names = "FH9989BP, DETV98-05, 998-534"
system = re.findall(r'(\d{4})|([-A-Z0-9-]*)',names)
```

but then I am getting this
*[('', 'FH9989BP'), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', 'DETV98-05'), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', '998-534'), ('', '')]*

What do I need to do to get
*9989, DETV98-05, 998-534*?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the exact rule why you want "FH9989BP" to return "9989" and the other values remain the same? Furthermore, you don't have a list but a comma-seperated string. Do you want a list to be returned though?

Comment: It's a legacy thing. Earlier systems had FH989BP style names but were only referred to by the 4 digits, newer have the other variants. To stay consistent with already existing data the earlier systems should still return the 4 digits only.I have a bunch of log files and I need to get the system name out of the file. That part isn't a problem. I was just putting the potential variations of the system names in a string for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes that you want to find either:

1. A four digit number, surrounded on both sides by uppercase letters, or
2. A hyphenated term, with each term containing either numbers or uppercase letters

```py
import re
names = "FH9989BP, DETV98-05, 998-534"
matches = re.findall(r'[A-Z]+(\d{4})[A-Z]+|([A-Z0-9]+-[A-Z0-9]+)', names)
matches = [x[0] if x[0] != '' else x[1] for x in matches]
print(matches)  # ['9989', 'DETV98-05', '998-534']
```

The regex uses an *alternation*, which first attempts to find four digits surrounded by letters.  That failing, the regex pattern would target a hyphenated term.

Comment: Thanks, incorporated it in my larger script and after some minor changes it's working now. Changes only to reflect the slightly different string from which I am trying to extract the system name, not the basic logic. Works like a charm now. Also got a deeper understanding of the alternation.